# get empty value when passing two parametres to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract two variables which I passed to shell script like :

```
/XDRI_RV_LOAD.KSH 20220617 rv_tiers
```

Inside the shell script, I write :

```
date_ctrlm=$1
branche=$2
echo "TEST 1 : " $date_ctrlm
echo " TEST 2 :" $branche
```

So that I get this

```
TEST 1 :  20220617
 TEST 2 :
```

I don't know why the job does not extract the 2 param. In fact, I should get also

```
TEST 2 : rv_tiers
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: @0stone0 it show `/bin/bash`

Comment: Have you added a shebang the top of the file?

Comment: I just tried it, using `sh test.sh one two` and I got these results: `TEST 1 :  one` and `TEST 2 : two`.

Comment: yes `#!/bin/ksh
# @(#)`

Comment: note that I am working in shell code which call other tools : `. /d/tools/tools.profile
jobInit ${0} "$@"
jobExport
set -- $_JOB_CMDLINE`

Comment: @Dominique, it is a `.KSH` file not `.SH`

Comment: @SA2018: whatever. I launched the script as `./test.ksh one two` and the results were fine too.

Comment: this is really weird

Comment: @Fravadona, I did `branche="$2"` but always empty

Comment: I just tried `if [[ -z $2 ]];
then 
    echo "No parameter passed."
else
    echo "Parameter passed = $2"
fi` and I get `No parameter passed`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace :

```
jobInit ${0} "$@"
```

By

```
jobInit ${0} "$*"
```